# creating dataframe of vectors and arrange it o three row levels in R

Tags: r

HI everyone i have 3 vectors:

```
v1 = c(32,60,20)
v2 = c(60,10,40)
v3 = c(90,45,15)
```

i want to put them into DataFrame as shown in the screenshot below
where:
low for value less than 30
average for values more than 30 and less 50
High for value more than 50.

the DataFrame should be like this:

```
          v1 : v2 : v3
low:
average:
High:
```

[image]

Comment: Hi - you probably want to give your vectors different names. As you write it, you only have a single vector defined 3 times. It would also be nice if you would show the exact output you want for the given input--your input has 4 values < 30, but your output only has space for 3, so it's not clear what you want. And lastly, what have you tried?

Comment: Actually i have tweets from twitter, and i have extracted 3 levels of users according to followers count (low , average and high) and i want to put it in a data frame accourding to how many statuses they have posted and also i have statuses count with 3 leves (low,average and high).

Comment: the example above is same idea where v1 is users with low followers count ,average is v2 , high is v3. and the columns are for users statuses count

Comment: You've given sample input with 9 values. Can you fill in the desired output with those 9 values so we can understand what you want?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for is actually possible the way you have drawn it. For example, V3 would have two low values whereas V1 and V2 would only have one. Gregor's first comment already hints at this issue.

Comment: its just an example but i have edited the value, i want the values of vectors to be re arranged according to the rows

Comment: Please show exactly what output you want for that sample input. You keep describing it, and it does not make sense to me. Please show it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `cut` to split the vectors in the classes Low, Average and High. With `table` you can get the counts per class.

```
v1 <- c(32,60,20)
v2 <- c(60,10,40)
v3 <- c(90,45,15)

. <- lapply(mget(c("v1", "v2", "v3")), cut, c(-Inf,30,50,Inf), c("Low", "Average", "High"))
sapply(., table)
#        v1 v2 v3
#Low      1  1  1
#Average  1  1  1
#High     1  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what you asked for but in my opinion it is a more sensible way of coding your data (long format).

```
#### Library ####
library(tidyverse)

#### Create Vars ####
v1 = c(30,60,20)
v2 = c(40,10,30)
v3 = c(90,20,10)

#### Make Data Frame ####
df <- data.frame(v1,v2,v3)
df_fix <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
               names_to = "Variable",
               values_to = "Score") %>% 
  mutate(Variable_Type = ifelse(Score < 30,
                       "Low",
                       ifelse(Score > 50,
                              "High",
                              "Average"))) %>% 
  select(-Variable) 

df_fix
```

Which gives you this cleaner column by variable format:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 2
  Score Variable_Type
  <dbl> <chr>        
1    30 Average      
2    40 Average      
3    90 High         
4    60 High         
5    10 Low          
6    20 Low          
7    20 Low          
8    30 Average      
9    10 Low
```

And if you want to leave the variable names in place by row:

```
df_row <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
               names_to = "Variable",
               values_to = "Score") %>% 
  mutate(Variable_Type = ifelse(Score < 30,
                                "Low",
                                ifelse(Score > 50,
                                       "High",
                                       "Average")))
    df_row
```

Which looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  Variable Score Variable_Type
  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>        
1 v1          30 Average      
2 v2          40 Average      
3 v3          90 High         
4 v1          60 High         
5 v2          10 Low          
6 v3          20 Low          
7 v1          20 Low          
8 v2          30 Average      
9 v3          10 Low
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but i want 3 X 3 DataFrame so the column are v1,v2,v3 and rows low, average and high.

Comment: I've seen your edit and added a comment above. Theoretically the way you have drawn it out doesn't work unless you have a way of storing multiple values within the same row by column observation, which in this case you can't.

Comment: i have edited the values so there is no multiple values within the same row, this question is just an example to more big data. i believe if i find solution for this one i can do it for bigger data from tweeter

Comment: Wouldn't you almost certainly run into issues with this if your previous example comes up with a ton of other values?

Comment: maybe i can re arrange the vectors to have 3 different values each time

Comment: That would either be arbitrary or reduce a ton of information in your data. Is there some good reason you are trying to arrange it in this way? I feel what I proposed avoids a lot of that issue. The only way I foresee this sort of setup working out is if you were working with category by category counts, but doing so in this way is not what that entails because one is a classifier of the other and is therefore constrained to what fits the logical rules assigned.